# Sum of Nilpotent Nonzero Complex Matrix and Adjoint is non-Nilpotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm working on the following problem in order to study for a preliminary exam coming up:

Suppose $A\neq 0$ is a nilpotent complex matrix. Prove that $A+A^*$ is not nilpotent.

The adjoint $A^*$ is defined to be the conjugate transpose of $A$.

My first thought was to use the fact that $A$ has all zero eigenvalues because it is nilpotent, and try to show that the $tr(A+A^*)=tr(A^*)\neq0$. This seems to be a dead end however. I could compute powers of $(A+A^*)$ but I have no information about commutativity of $A$ and $A^*$ that I can think of.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: $A+A^*$ is Hermitian, and so diagonalisable.

Comment: Thank you!!! I used this to show that if $A+A^*$ is nilpotent, then $A+A^*=0$. Using the properties of adjoints and complex numbers, I showed this contradicts $A\neq0$ assumption.